# NaN values in pointcloudXYZ

Tags: kinect, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I converted sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 from kinect to pointcloudXYZ. But some of the values are nan

I found 1 post about this issue but it doesnt clearly explain it (http://answers.ros.org/question/11750/problems-of-nan-positions-when-converting-pointcloud2-to-pclpointcloud-pointxyzrgb/)

Please anyone explain if my code is wrong or its just that kinect sometimes not reliable

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205928/nan-values-in-pointcloudxyz/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not a question of reliability; it's a major difference between 2D/3D sensors:

### 2D sensors

You always get information from the sensors for each pixel of the image (as long as they are no dead pixels); if no light hits the sensor the image will be plain black; meaning the 3 channels R,G,B (from the bayer filter) will be 0; that is the information.

### 3D sensors

3D sensors are different in many ways; while most of all rely on 2D sensors (one or multiple of them); the depth of a point might not always be possible to be computed.

Imagine a [stereo camera](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stereo_camera), the stereo-correspondence between the pixel of the left image and the right pixel might sometimes fail because of occlusions, algorithm weaknesses, bad lightning etc... When the stereo-correspondence fails; the Z coordinate of the point cannot be calculated; thus it is filled with NaN. The X and Y coordinates should never be NaN because these are the coordinates of the point related to the pixel matrix.

### Conclusion

It is perfectly normal to have "holes" in the Kinect (or any other 3D sensor) cloud; it's very unlikely you'll get a point cloud with 0 NaN values.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2